# App bundle size not reduce after using Play Asset delivery in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a question about play asset delivery that is my game size is 60 MB but I want to reduce my apk size upto 30 MB. Is play asset delivery suitable for this or not?
and other question is .. we use PAD only for those games which are more than 150 MB ?

Answer (score 0):

**As per documentation of Google PAD(play asset delivery) recommended to have it for the app size more than 150 MB.**

Use the **editor logs** in unity to understand the reason behind your app size, based on that you can use **delivery modes** which is suitable.

I would recommend you to go for **Install-time** delivery, which helps you to set up the app assets while installing.

Also if you need assets only on-demand choose **on-demand** delivery mode to achieve the lower app size.

if not try **Addressables**, please share the type of assets which you have in the game, so that get a better understanding to suggest more ways.

Thank you

Comment: i am using addressable with pad.
But the issue is that my bundle size is not reduce with this.On testing my bundle size is same as before PAD implementation.

Comment: do you want to reduce asset bundle size? are you downloading it on-demand or loading it with the app itself?

PAD will take care of app size which carries assets loaded in the app itself.

Need more details if it was misunderstood?